# How do I pass String Arrays between methods in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, pass-by-reference

I have an assignment that requires me to create a string array based on user input and then pass the array to another method. I also have to convert some of the string array to int (which I have no trouble doing). My problem is that whenever I'm trying to pass the array into the Public Lab method, I'm getting an error message saying that "The type of expression must be an array type but it resolved to string". Can someone please teach me how to fix this, I've been working on this for hours and it is due shortly.

This is my code:

```
     import java.util.Scanner;
     public class Lab 
     {
    String[] input = new String[4];
    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);{
    input[0] = keyboard.nextLine();
    String name = input[0];
    input[1] = "244";
    input[2] = "214";
    int classSize = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
    int numTA = Integer.parseInt(input[2]);
    }

    public Lab(String input) // input is the string of form a,b,c 
    {
    String[] data = new String[4];
    data[0] = input[0]; //THIS IS AN ERROR!!!

        /* data[0] is lab name (ALL CAPS)
         * data[1] is lab enrollment
         * data[2] is # teaching assistants 
         * if less than 20 students per TA, set string to Very Well Covered
         * if at most 30 students per TA, set string to Well Covered
         * if at most 35 students per TA, set string to Covered
         * if more than 35 students per TA, set to Barely Covered
         * USE TYPE CONVERSIONS ^^^^^
         */
```

Comment: What is `input` in that scope?

Comment: Probably giving you an error because you defined your array of strings in the first method (I believe main but you do not seem to have written it down here). Try making input an instance variable by defining it before getting into the first method and then, you'll be able to access from wherever in the class. Use "public static".

Answer (score 2):

Make `public Lab(String input)` to `public Lab(String[] input)` to take String array as input parameter.

Comment: Wow, I can't seem to avoid these ridiculously silly mistakes. Thank you!

Comment: @JamesWashington Tip: To avoid such mistakes, read your code out loud using regular English speech. If you first read `( String input )` as "pass a single piece of text to the constructor", then you might realize the error while reading out `data[0] = input[0]` as "Extract first element from the array of Strings named 'input'…".

Answer (score 0):

You can even use variable arguments, like:

```
public Lab(String... input){
//your code goes here
}
```

Variable arguments are used to pass any number of arguments as parameters.
Though variable arguments are used when you give any number of arguments, use it carefully as it has certain limitations:

i. If you are going to have two or more arguments of same or different type, you must get the variable argument as the last parameter.

ii. You can not have more than one variable argument in your method or constructor.

You can not use variable args as return type, instead which you can use arrays. You can have variable arguments for any primitive types or any objects(like *int... a* or *float... b* or *Employee... emp*). 
You can always use them just like arrays,i.e., you can access the elements by their index. I always use var args in my main method(*public static void main(String... args){}*).